# Error al intentar poner un parámetro al Main del sistema

Tags: c#

Estoy desarrollando un sistema en C#, tengo un proyecto que es un menú principal y llama varios procesos ya compilados en .exe, necesito pasar el usuario y la clave a cada .exe
Al modificar el `Main` con un parámetro `string Usuario` me da un error de

> "El programa no contiene ningún método 'Main' estático adecuado para
>   un punto de entrada"

```
    using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Proyecto1
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Punto de entrada principal para la aplicación.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(**string usuario**)
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new MenuPrin(usuario));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Es un programa de consola? ¿Cómo le pasas el parámetro usuario? El error que se produce es lógico..

Comment: Apenas lo estoy desarrollando de esta forma, es una aplicación de escritorio, es solo un formulario MenuPrin al que le pongo un parámetro Usuario, y pretendo enviarlo desde el sistema principal, el problema se me presenta el el archivo Program.cs, ni siquiera lo puedo correr, lo que le incluir el program es lo que esta entre **

Comment: Para recibir un parámetro en el main, debes usar el parámetro `string[] args`, ahí te deje un pequeño ejemplo de respuesta, cualquier cosa decime!

Answer (score 1):

[Para recibir parámetros por línea de comando](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/command-line-arguments), debes recibir un arreglo de `string` en tu método main, este puedes recorrerlo, y recién ahí obtendrás tu parámetro `usuario`.

Por ejemplo

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread] 
    //Si te fijas, ahora recibo un string[] en lugar de un string
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //De esta manera, asumiendo que sólo pases un parámetro, en la posición 0 de args
        //Se encontrará el dato que buscas..
        string usuario = args[0];
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MenuPrin(usuario));
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda Juan ya me corrió perfecto